# python writing to different file

Tags: python

I'm a huge python noob. Trying to write simple script that will split a line in a file where it see's a "?"

line in Input file (inputlog.log):
`http://website.com/somejunk.jpg?uniqid&=123&an=1234=123`

line in output file (outputlog.log):
`http://website.com/somejunk.jpg uniqid&=123&an=1234=123`

The goal here is to end up with a file that has 2 columns:

Here's my code it kinda works except it wont write to the 2nd file

> "TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

```
import re

a = raw_input("what file do you want to open? ")
b = raw_input("what is the file you want to save to? ")

with open(a, 'r') as f1:
    with open(b,'w') as f2:
        data = f1.readlines()  
        print "This is the line: ", data #for testing
        for line in data:
            words= re.split("[?](.*)$",line)
            print "Here is the Split: ", words #for testing
            f2.write(words)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: You don't need the f1.close() and f2.close() since you are using "with". It automatically closes the handle.

Comment: Vahn, thanks Good to know !  @hayley, what does your edit do (new to stack overflow too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that 'words' is a list. You cannot write that to your file. You need to convert it back to a string. Also, you need to pay attention when converting it back to make sure that you create the spacing/split you want between the string.

You should do something like this.

```
words = ' '.join(words)
```

Pay close attention to the space inside the single quotes. That indicates it will put a space between your strings.

Finally, you then make your call to:

```
f2.write(words)
```

Upon making that change, I tested your code and it successfully split and wrote them to the file per your specification.

Comment: Sweet jeebus thanks!! that did the trick. I added that line under my regex split and was able to write to file.